# CORS asyncronous ajax call with xhrFields is not working across all browsers (IE8)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

I'm making an ajax call across a cross domain url and it fails in IE8 using below code.It fails in IE8 with error as object or property is not defined, and gives response as undefined.
I have set , $.support.cors = true;

```
$.ajax({                        
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    url: "http://test/price",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: jsonData,                     
                     xhrFields: {
                             withCredentials: true
                     },
                    success: function (response) {
                      }
                     error: function (xhr, exception) {
                           }
```

The above code works perfectly in firefox and chrome browsers. To make it work in IE8, I removed below part of code
`xhrFields: { withCredentials: true  },`

Now it works in IE8, IE8+ browsers but fails in chrome and firefox and complains as "401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied"

I even tried forcing in header section in ajax call using below code, but it's of no use.

```
headers: {  
    "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Accept",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "POST"
}
```

I tried all the suggestions in some posts, but none worked
Can someone please help me fix it in IE8+, chrome and firefox browsers.

Comment: I figured out the issue, IE8 doesn't have a definition for the object - withCredentials,so it's failing. I'm using an if - else condition like below so that option can eb suppressed in IE but availble in Firefox/Chrome, but my if-else doesn' twork as expected.


xhrFields: (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ? {} :  { withcredentials: true },

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Figured the issue, and was able to fix it.